# Java Multimap of naturally ordered keys but collections sorted in the order the elements were added

Tags: java, sorting, maps, guava, multimap

Is there an easy way to implement a `Multimap` that is like a `TreeMultimap` in the sense that the keys take a natural ordering, but also like an `ArrayListMultimap` in the sense that the collections are sorted in the order the values were added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`MultimapBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) to create combinations of features you need. From javadoc:

> A builder for a multimap implementation that allows customization of the backing map and value collection implementations used in a particular multimap.
>
> This can be used to easily configure multimap data structure implementations not provided explicitly in `com.google.common.collect`, for example:
>
> ```
> ListMultimap<String, Integer> treeListMultimap =
>       MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
> SetMultimap<Integer, MyEnum> hashEnumMultimap =
>      MultimapBuilder.hashKeys().enumSetValues(MyEnum.class).build();
> ```